# How can I fix my function to print out a Huffman tree to screen?

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree, nodes, huffman-code

I have a huffman tree and I am attempting to print it out to screen, with the right branches extending horizontally and the left branches going downwards. My function is below. IsNodeNamSingleChar() just returns a '*' if the node is one of the intermediate ones.

```
void PrintBranches(Node * Top)
{
  if(Top == NULL){
    return;
  }
  if(Top->right != NULL){
    printf("-%c", IsNodeNameSingleChar(Top));
    Top = Top->right;
    PrintBranches(Top);
  }
  else{
    printf("%c\n|\n", IsNodeNameSingleChar(Top));
    Top = Top->left;
    PrintBranches(Top);
  }
}
```

I know that this isn't right, but I can't get my head around how I should fix it. Currently, this prints out (for a test file I'm using):

```
  -*  -*  -*B
|
```

Comment: I don't know the exact format of your tree, but generally in a binary tree both branches may be non-null, so you would have to print both of them: `if (Top->right != null) PrintBranches(Top->right); if (Top->left != null) PrintBranches(Top->left);`.

Comment: Cross-posted from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/3wkolw/really_struggling_to_recursively_print_a_huffman/). OP, please tell us when you cross-post so people don't have to answer your question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you that I am going to write out in 'pseudo-type' code... because I think what you really need is an algorithm that will work.....

.... this solution has two recursive functions that call each other.

It should be called with

```
printNodeRight(&topNode, 0);
```

functions are...

```
int printNodeRight(Node * pTop, int indent)
{  
  if (current node pTop is not end of branch)
  {
    printf("*-");
    printNodeRight(pTop->Right,indent+1);
    printNodeLeft(pTop->Left,indent);
  } else {
    printf("%c\n", pTop->value);
    for (loop indent times) 
    {
      printf("| ");
    }
    printf("\n);
  }
  return 0;
}

int printNodeLeft(Node * pTop, int indent)
{  
  for (loop (indent-1) times) 
  {
    printf("| ");
  }
  printNodeRight(pTop,indent);
  return 0;
}
```

Note that this code should produce trees like the following...

```
*-*-b
| |
| c
|
a

*-*-*-b
| | |
| | *-d
| | |
| | e
| |
| *-*-*-g
| | | | 
| | | *-h
| | | |
| | | i
| | |
| | j
| |
| c
|
a
```

---

original answer

This is a particularly difficult and interesting challenge because of the way that text is printed to the screen.

so for example with the recursive routine that you have it will be impossible to print the following tree

```
  -*-*-b
   | | 
   a c
```

because you will start by printing

```
  -*-*-b
```

then c would print directly after b to get

```
  -*-*-bc
  |
```

if you change your printf from "%c\n|\n" to "\n|\n%c" you would get

```
  -*-*-b
  |
  c
```

but the fundamental problem is that with your recursive function you will print c **before** you print a.

Your problem is on the second line of

```
  -*-*-b
   | | 
   a c
```

you need to print a before c, but your recursive routine will get to c before it gets to a so it will be difficult (?impossible) to go back and print a in front of c --- also when you get to print the second line you need to know how many spaces along to print c and a.... overall it is quite a difficult challenge - it may be possible to do it by moving the cursor about left right up and down carefullly.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I understand. Using two functions may be what I've been looking for!